# PHP doesn't seem to recognize this 'if then' statement

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I have 2 wordpress templates, each using a different header.
In each header, I give a value to my $pagekids element. For example:

```
<?php $pagekids = 'yes'; ?>
```

Then each template calls a plugin where I have the following statement:

```
if ($pagekids == 'yes' ) {$imageSubPath = 'bg-images';}
else {$imageSubPath = 'bg-kidimages';}
```

which allow the header to pick an image in a different directory (bg-images or bg-kidimages).
However, this doesn't work and both templates always pick images in the same directory. But if I display the value of $pagekids  on a page, it displays the correct one depending on the template.

Any idea why this isn't working? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `$pagekids === 'yes'`?

Comment: nneonneo, won't make a difference because there is no value that could be coerced to `'yes'` that isn't that string already.

Comment: You say both pick the same directory, which one is that? Does it always evaluate to true or false? Also, do `var_dump($pagekids);` and make sure there are no extra characters around there (verify the length).

Comment: nneonneo: yes, I tried, it didn't help.

sachleen: no matter which value (yes or no) i put in my "if", it always uses whatever directory is in the "else" line.
Where should I place the var_dump?

Thanks guys!

Comment: the plugin is probably called before the header file. `echo` something and `die` in both the plugin and header, and see which message is executed first.

Comment: Try to echo out the $pagekids variable immediately before the conditional to make sure the variable is even making it that far.  The statement looks fine... I question the presence of the input value.

Comment: Yes, the plugin was probably called before the header.
I found a way to achieve what I wanted with jQuery tho.

Answer (score 0):

At least the problem is not with php you provided because it's correct.